# Does not change button text after time is set...can't figure out what is wrong.?

Tags: java, android

What is wrong with my code it display the time picker you select the time but does not set the text. The onclick event display the time picker but the On settime method does not set the button text to the time selected.

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            final Calendar c =
            Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,true);}
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

        if(view.getId()==R.id.button1){
                Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button1.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);}

        else if(view.getId()==R.id.button2){
                Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                button2.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
        }
        else
        button4.setText (hourOfDay+":"+minute);

    }
}
```

Comment: Button belongs to which view hierarchy?

Comment: I  don't understand your question but...this is the code for onclick                                              I               DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(); newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"timePicker");

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the way you're initializing your buttons and their views.
Check if you're correcting binding views.

Comment: I checked and something like that do exist... don't know   why?  What do you suggest....

Comment: please post your full code. I'll get the views right for you.